# Delphi FMX TabOrder and frames bug

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

using the Delphi 10.2.2 I encountered a problem with TabOrder when using frames.

Look at the following picture, I set the tabOrder and expect the focus to move as follow: Edit with TabOrder0 -> Edit inside a frame -> Edit with TabOrder 2 -> Edit Inside a frame, inside a  layout -> Edit with TabOrder0

[image: Sample application picture]

Instead the focus move using tab, generate the following problems:

1. Edit with TabOrder0 -> Edit inside a frame -> Edit with TabOrder0 
   **The focus never reach Edit with TabOrder 2**
2. If I force the focus (using the mouse) to Edit with TabOrder 2:
   Edit with TabOrder 2-> Edit Inside a frame, inside a layout -> Edit Inside a frame, inside a layout.
   **The focus never leave the last edit.**

Does anyone knows a workaround to make the TabOrder behave as expected?

Follow a snippet of the .fmx

The form:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 337
  ClientWidth = 414
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Edit4: TEdit
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    TabOrder = 0
    Text = 'TabOrder 0'
    Position.X = 48.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 16.000000000000000000
  end
  inline Frame21: TFrame2
    Position.X = 40.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 80.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 320.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 62.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 1
  end
  object Edit5: TEdit
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    TabOrder = 3
    Text = 'TabOrder 2'
    Position.X = 48.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 160.000000000000000000
  end
  object Layout3: TLayout
    Position.X = 40.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 200.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 345.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 121.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 4
    inline Frame22: TFrame2
      Position.X = 8.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 51.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 320.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 62.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TabOrder = 0
    end
    object Label1: TLabel
      Position.X = 24.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 24.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 305.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      Text = 'TabOrder 3: TEdit inside frame, inside TLayout'
      TabOrder = 2
    end
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Position.X = 40.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 56.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 305.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'TabOrder 1: TEdit inside frame'
    TabOrder = 2
  end
end
```

The frame:

```
object Frame2: TFrame2
  Size.Width = 320.000000000000000000
  Size.Height = 62.000000000000000000
  Size.PlatformDefault = False
  object Edit1: TEdit
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    TabOrder = 0
    Position.X = 200.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 24.000000000000000000
  end
end
```

Comment: I can confrm the issue on Delphi 10.1 Berlin (I don't have Tokyo installed), but I don't have a cure. Please submit a bug report to the suppliers quality portal.

Comment: Thanks @TomBrunberg for confirming the issue even on previuos version. Is my intention to open a bug report, I am waiting Emarcadero to fix my account to login there...

Comment: It took a while, but now the issue has been added to quality central: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20162

Comment: Great, thanks. I voted for it.